# Proper way to move content in bootstrap container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If I use a container. For instance 
and then I use position relative. Position relative will mess with the container by moving left and right.Wouldn't this cause render issues for devices when i'm specifying the grids and then moving the content around?
What would be the proper way to move the content without messing up the grids I setup with col-md-#/col-sm-#

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>
<head>
<title>Bicycle App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>

        <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Andy's Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
</div>
</div>
    </div><!--Header Container-->
    </div>
<div class="bikeSelector">
        <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6"><!-- end class not needed -->
        <div class="chooseTitle">
            Choose Your Bicycle
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"><!-- you missed md from offset, end class not needed -->

          Test

    </div>
 </div>


</div>
</div> 


<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
.products {
    position :relative;
    left: 500px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code and explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I know I can offset columns, but should I use <br> to get one container under another? What is the proper way of moving the content under other containers? See screenshot for reference

Comment: @user6680 please clarify in your post how you want to move content around.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are asking about basic Bootstrap Grid formatting, or if you need clarification on how to utilize Bootstrap's responsive Grid resizing.   You may want to revisit the Grid documentation though, as in either case your formatting is incorrect: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: That actually clarified it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your html is wrong in places for what you're trying to achieve.

Try this (not tested but should get you started)

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-6'><!-- end class not needed -->
        <div class="chooseTitle">
            Choose Your Bicycle
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"><!-- you missed md from offset, end class not needed -->
        <div class="products">
            {{bike.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
 </div><!--bike controller row-->
```

[Here's a bootply which is a great way to test before you add](http://www.bootply.com/ohqVpMxZRw)

Comment: How come it formats properly in bootply, but not in my browser. See updated screenshot and html above. I used your code

Comment: In the bootply linked above there is no `.container` element.  Once you place the code provided into a `.container` everything adjusts to fit within the confines of that class, which by default has a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks Robert. That clarified everything for me. I got it working now

Comment: One question though. Can I use <br> to push content down or is that not proper with the grids? Or maybe I should use margins in css? If not, then what's the best way to push the content in each row down from the top of the page.

Comment: Don't use a `<br>` to _"clear"_ your content or create _"faux margins/padding"_ with them. Use CSS margin/padding. Again, please be specific in your original post as to what the intended layout should be. Right now it's anyone's guess as to what the intended layout is and can only guess at what the appropriate answer is. By being vague you might get answer that works but might not be optimal.